# Codeigniter cron job from CLI throws memcached errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to set up the cron jobs for my Codigniter application, however when I run the cron, it throws me memcached errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php on line 50
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php on line 50

Although I have no idea why this is throwing all the time, I can't find any errors in my cron job file, nor how to solve this problem because I don't know where this is being called, I looked into my autoloaded libraries and helpers, none of them seem to be wrong.

I also can confirm that memcached is installed, if I visit my site, memcached indeed works.

I tried suppressing the `get()` in `Cached_memcached.php` with a `@`, but this didn't help because no output is shown (but there is supposed to be output shown).

The command I run for the cron (user: `www-data`) is:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/index.php cron run cron
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64.

This is my cron file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cron extends CI_Controller {

    var $current_cron_tasks = array('cron');

    public function run($mode)
    {
        if($this->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            if(isset($mode) || !empty($mode))
            {
                if(in_array($mode, $this->current_cron_tasks))
                {
                    $this->benchmark->mark('cron_start');

                    if($mode == 'cron')
                    {
                        if($this->cache->memcached->get('currency_cache'))
                        {
                            if($this->cache->memcached->delete('currency_cache'))
                            {
                                $this->load->library('convert');
                                $this->convert->get_cache(true);
                            }
                        }

                        echo $mode . ' executed successfully';  
                    }

                    $this->benchmark->mark('cron_end');
                    $elapsed_time = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('cron_start', 'cron_end');

                    echo $elapsed_time;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: show us the code in index.php

Comment: Why the downvote? Explain why there was a downvote?

Comment: Please post your index.php or the applicable cron job that runs and triggers the error.  The memcached object was never initialized in CI_Driver_Memcached, that is `$this->_memcached` is never setup in the driver.

Comment: I suspect the downvote was because there's no code. You'll need to show your Cron::run() method at the very least

Comment: Edited my post to add the code.

Comment: Seems like a silly question, but I assume you've loaded the memcache driver and the cache library? `$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcache', 'backup' => 'dummy'));` Also, does the code work in the browser or fail there too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing to try would be the following to determine if memcached is supported.

```
var_dump($this->cache->memcached->is_supported());
```

The second thing to ensure is that you've got a `memcached.php` file in `application/config/`

It should contain a multidimensional array of memcached hosts with the following keys:

- `host`
- `port`
- `weight`

The following example defines two servers. The array keys `server_1` and `server_2` are irrelevant, they can be named however.

```
$config = array(
    'server_1' => array(
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'      => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
    ),
    'server_2' => array(
        'host'      => '127.0.0.2',
        'port'      => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
    )
);
```

The next thing I'd try is check to see if the controller can be run in the web browser as opposed to the CLI or if you get the same error.

Also, explicitly loading the memcached driver might be worthwhile trying. The following will load the `memcached` driver, and failing that call upon the `file` cache driver.

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'file'));
```

Using this method allows you to call `$this->cache->get();` to take into account the fallback too.

Another thing to check is that you're not using separate php.ini files for web and CLI.

On Ubuntu it's located in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And you should ensure that the following line is present, and not commented out

```
extension=memcache.so
```

Alternatively, you can create a file `/etc/php5/cond.d/memcache.ini` with the same contents.

Don't forget to restart services after changing configuration files.

You can check memcached is indeed set up correctly using the CLI by executing the following

`php -i | grep memcache`

Comment: I have `memcached.php` similar to yours but with one server, also I get `true` for if memcached is supported. Finally, this as my loader: `$CI->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'apc'));` (which is loaded from an autoloaded library). It all works via my browser, but with CLI, it still throws me the error I get.

Comment: Woah! I didn't think about the CLI php.ini, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll award you the bounty in 6 hours.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$this->cache->memcached` is `NULL` (or otherwise uninitialized), meaning that the cache hasn't been initialized.

An easy fix would be to simply create the memcache object yourself. The proper fix, however, would be to look through the source and trace how the memcache object normally gets instantiated (look for `new Memcache` and set a `debug_print_backtrace()` there. Trace the debug stack back and compare it with what your cron does - look where it goes wrong then correct it). This is basic debugging btw, sorry.

Also, make sure you do load the drivers. If your cron uses a different bootstrap function than your normal index (never used CI, is that even possible?) then make sure that the memcache init is placed in the right location.

-edit-

`$this->cache->memcached` probably isn't actually `NULL`, but the actual connection to the Memcache server definitely wasn't made before you started calling `get()`.

Comment: But I autoload a library that initiates the memcached connection, thus it works (as I said above that memcached does work).

Comment: Exactly, you said it works on the website. But the cron is definitely something else than the website, starting with the fact that it's not initiated via a HTTP connection. This may change a lot of things in your code - for example, most cron scripts don't need memcache and CI may choose to disable it unless you explicitly activate it. This is why you should simply trace where it goes wrong, which is the fact that no Memcache instance is created by CI. I added some simple debug steps in my answer - just follow them :-)

Comment: But autoloaded libraries are not ignored, which should be getting the memcached running. I just found out it works on my localhost, but on my server it doesn't work, memcached *is* working and running.

Comment: Like I pointed out, the problem is not that the file doesn't get loaded, the problem is that the object is uninitialized. Having access to `new Memcache()` is one thing, actually doing it is something else. In your case it's probably the second thing going wrong, judging by the error. In fact, the Cache_memcached.php file seems to get loaded just fine. Also, this is strictly a PHP issue, not related to the memcached server itself.